# How do I have my XNA installer include external files

Tags: xna, installation

In my game, the developer creates a level txt that is loaded by the game, converted to a bin, and saves it by creating the bin at "Content\Testing_Grounds.bin".

This creates the file at:  "C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\SeniorSpringVideoGameProject\SeniorProjectGame\SeniorProjectGame\SeniorProjectGame\bin\x86\Debug\Content\Testing_Grounds.bin".

We then loaded the binary file by looking in "Content\Testing_Grounds.bin." I handle the conversion of txt->bin->level conversion myself.

This works while I am working with the project files before the installation takes place; it is apparent that these files within the ...bin\x86\Debug\Content... folder do not get included upon installation.

I thought since they were in the project folder that they'd be included. How do I make sure that they files are included? I want to stick with the built in XNA installer.

Answer (score 0):

If the files are part of your game you can add them to your content project by just dragging them in in visual studio.
Then access them via their asset name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add them to your content project just like any other file, or you could add them to your content folder and click the "Show All Files" button and right click the files "Include in project"

Adding via existing item (can be anywhere on disk)
[image: Adding via existing item]

Adding via including item (must be in content folder already)
[image: Adding via including item]

And of course, you can always [load a file](http://www.dotnetperls.com/file) yourself as if you were not in XNA.